# Deploying an individual feature

Tags: 2010, feature

I am using sharepoint software factory and have a number of features within it. How can I deploy an individual feature to my local dev farm, as opposed to the whole lot?

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about multiple features in a solution? I think we need some more info on this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feature - is a folder at 14 Hive\Template\Features with special xml markup files. Where are some restriction with feature deployment - it contains only xml markup files. To deploy, for example, assembly or pictures you have to use wsp package.
The functionality that you may name as "feature" can depend on some assembly or other files. You need to research your functionality dependence and when make next steps to move this functionality.